# Implementing a callback without AIDL

Tags: android, service, aidl

How can I implement a callback using `LocalBinder` without AIDL?

I've seen the examples of android LocalService.java but it only binds to the Service, there is not callback to the activity. The only callbacks example I see in the examples is the RemoteBinder.java but this uses AIDL and I want to avoid AIDL.

Thanks!